# get the last confirmed block in Tron network

Tags: blockchain, tron, tronweb

in the process of designing a cryptocurrency payment gateway, I faced this issue.
in tronweb library there is a method called [tronWeb.trx.getCurrentBlock()](https://tronweb.network/docu/docs/API%20List/trx/getCurrentBlock/)
the problem is this method returns the latest block but this block in unconfirmed. so how can I get the latest confirmed block?

I tried this way:
   `console.log("current block", await tronWeb.trx.getCurrentBlock());`
and quickly checked the result in tronscan but the block was unconfirmed and became confirmed after 15 secconds.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:

```
    let confirmedCurrentBlock = (await tronWeb.trx.getConfirmedCurrentBlock()).block_header.raw_data.number
```

This method is not mentioned in the document. I found it in the core modules of tronweb.

Hope it will be useful.